# Implement Policy Filter Rule on Open Source Mail Server

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, iredmail

I have an old mail server in `Linux 3.9.3`. And according to its `Server Monitor` Page. It seems an integrate of postfix, dovecot, apache, etc.
Due to its ancient version and not under maintenance web interface and limited hardware. I decided to migrate the mail server to iredmail on the virtualized CentOS. I almost did it, but there is an old feature that is not supported on the new server.

## Function description:

- There are multiple filter options that can be used to filter out messages such as time, message direction, subject/body content, size, etc. (Old Mail Server `Policy Filter / filter rules / Add` page [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huzfU.png))
- After filter out the e-mail, do something. Like delete, delay send, verify, bypass spam processor, forward, etc. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvqFP.png))

---

Now I want to implement these functions on iRedMail by myself but having no idea what to do (Maybe postfix policy server?). I guess it is feasible because the old server use the same MTA & MRA.

---

PS: I also posted in [iRedMail Forum](https://forum.iredmail.org/post76309.html). And the answer seems to be adding sieve filter plugin into dovecot. I will work on it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to serverfault. Please edit your post so the question becomes more clear